# node.js - get filename of ES6 subclass in superclass

Tags: node.js, class, inheritance, module, filenames

I am currently developing a node.js (v5.10.1) application that makes use of ES6 class syntax for module exposure although I am not sure, whether this is especially relevant for the problem I am facing.

Let's say I have the following directory structure:

```
/
|-command/
| |-walk/
| | |-config.json
| | |-walk.js
| |
| |-eat/
|   |-config.json
|   |-eat.js
|
|-core/
| |-app.js
| |-command.js
| |-config.json
| |-config.js
| |-job.js
| |-module.js
|
|-job/
| |-breathe/
|   |-config.json
|   |-breathe.js
|
|-init.js
```

The classes located in each `.js` file follow the following inheritance:

```
Config
|-App
|-Module
  |-Command
  | |-Eat
  | |-Walk
  | 
  |-Job
    |-Breathe
```

That works as planned.

Now the crucial part:
In my `Config` class I would like to implement a method that is made available to all the child and subchild (and so on) classes and accesses their individual directory (e.g. `/command/eat/` for `Eat` or `/core/` for `App`) to load the relevant `config.json` file which contains a default configuration.

Is there a "direct" way to identify the file in which the instantiated class resides? I can access the v8 call stack (e.g. using [stack-trace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stack-trace)) and iterate over it:

`config.js`

```
const path = require('path');
const stackTrace = require('stack-trace');
module.exports = class Config {
    constructor() {
        for (var callSite of stackTrace.get()) {
            if (callSite.getFunctionName() === this.constructor.name) {
                console.log(path.dirname(callSite.getFileName()));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Is this the most straightforward solution or do you have any recommendations or concerns?

Thanks in advance,
David